# How can I get CKEditor 5 "Link" dialog box to pin to custom DOM element instead of 'document.body'

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm building a Vue.js web application. I'm using CKEditor in a form that is placed inside a modal window. By design, the user's focus is "trapped" in the modal. In CKEditor, when user clicks the "Link" icon in toolbar, the editor opens a dialog box and attaches the new DOM element to 'document.body'. With respect to the DOM, the "Link" dialog is now outside of trapped focus. The user cannot click or tab his way to the "Link" dialog input.

I dug into the ckeditor5-ui source and found relevant code in balloonpanelview.js. I've unsuccessfully tried to configure CKEditor based on    https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_utils_dom_position-Options.html

In my Vue.js component, I have:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
...
  data: () => ({
    editor: ClassicEditor,
    editorConfig: {
      toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'link'],
    },
    ...
  })
...
```

I want the CKEditor "Link" dialog DOM element to be attached to a DOM element id that I specify.

Answer (score 5):

In Vuetify dialog component is required to disable retain-focus

```
<v-dialog :retain-focus="false" />
```

Comment: That did the trick, I no longer loose focus on my hyperlink edit textbox with that option

Answer (score 0):

There may be much time since you opened the issue. However... This issue was happening to me too. This is happening because Bootstrap modal trap the focus in the active modal. If you're using bootstrap-vue, do this.

- In your `<b-modal>` add the prop `no-enforce-focus`.

`no-enforce-focus` is reactive. To properly apply this workaround you can use this prop with a variable, that detects when your CKeditor have focus. If have focus, disable the enforce focus. If doesn't have, restore it. You can apply it by the following way:

```
<template>
    <b-modal
     ...
     :no-enforce-focus="editorFocus">
    <ckeditor
     ...
     @focus="toggleEditorFocus(true)"
     @blur="toggleEditorFocus(false)"
    />
    </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 ...
 data () {
  return {
   editorFocus: false
  }
 },
 methods: {
   toggleEditorFocus (val = !this.editorFocus) {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.editorFocus = val
   }, 10)
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

I know the `setTimeout` is a tricky method, but at least is working now for me.